# type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool' of 'test' when I use map function

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, statefulwidget

I have a StatefulWidget widget with a LinkedHashMap member done like this:

```
LinkedHashMap _items = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<dynamic>>();
```

Now I need to filter the items inside the `List<dynamic>` items of the Map.

I use this code to filter:

```
function filter(_items) {
    return _items.map((day, items) {
        return new MapEntry(day, items.where((i) {
          return i.stringProperty.contains(widget.filter);
        }).toList());
    });
}
```

But I get the error in the subject

> type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool' of 'test'

Comment: Similar problem with Dart version 2.7.2, and the ternary operator trick solves it. I am not even using a function like `contains`, but a straight boolean test (`a>0`). Perhaps some bug or regression somewhere. BTW the `test` is the callback passed to `where`, according to the [language reference](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-collection/ListMixin/where.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved with this code:

```
function filter(_items) {
    return _items.map((day, items) {
        return new MapEntry(day, items.where((i) {
          return i.stringProperty.contains(widget.filter) ? true : false;
        }).toList());
    });
}
```

It seems the `contains` function does not return a bool value.

Comment: `contains` does indeed return a boolean.  Something else is interfering.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz the solution that worked is pretty clear, the problem was the return value of the contains function. I am not able to find out something that interferes.

Comment: I resolved it with a similar approach. Using either "? true : false" or "as bool" for contains. Although, curious why it wouldn't accept the result of contains method. As documentation says it should return a bool - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html

Answer (score 4):

I believe this will also work, still not sure why it doesn't return a bool though

```
function filter(_items) {
    return _items.map((day, items) {
        return new MapEntry(day, items.where((i) {
          return (i.stringProperty.contains(widget.filter)) as bool;
        }).toList());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where method returns a list, so you don't need to use toList(), and you should specify the return type of map method when you are using it.

```
  filter(_items) {
    return _items.map<String, List<bool>>((day, items) {
      return MapEntry(
        day, items.where((i) => i.stringProperty.contains(widget.filter)),
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: shouldn't I return `<String, List<dynamic>>` instead of `<String, List<bool>>`?

Comment: anyway I tried with both `bool` and `dynamic` but I still get the error. I am not even able to understand where this error occurs